# mysql_field_name into array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare the field names in the table against the $_GET field names and if it exists in the table create a Query string, and i am trouble loading the mysql_field_name into an array if i do them individually like  `$t1 = mysql_field_name($result,1);` it works but loading them all like `$vars = mysql_field_name($result);` dose not seem to work.

This dose not work

```
$query = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_prof");
$vars = mysql_field_name($result);

foreach ($vars as $v)
{
    if (isset($_GET[$v]))
    {
        $query[] = $v.' = "'.addslashes($_GET[$v]).'"';
    }
}
$query = implode(' AND ', $query);
```

This works

```
$t1 = mysql_field_name($result,1);
$t2 = mysql_field_name($result,2);
$t3 = mysql_field_name($result,3);
$t4 = mysql_field_name($result,4);
$t5 = mysql_field_name($result,5);


    $query = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_prof");
    $vars = array('$t1', '$t2', '$t3', '$t4', '$t5'); 

    foreach ($vars as $v)
    {
        if (isset($_GET[$v]))
        {
            $query[] = $v.' = "'.addslashes($_GET[$v]).'"';
        }
    }
    $query = implode(' AND ', $query);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-field-name.php

The second parameter in this function is NOT optional, so you have to take your second approach.

If you want make it dynamic anyway, you can use the mysql_num_field function, which gives you the number of columns. Afterwards you can build a loop, which iterates this much times, calling everytime the mysql_field_name function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your current approach work, I guess you could do something like:

```
//Get fields in table
$numberOfFields = mysql_num_fields($result) - 1;

$fields = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfFields; $i++) {
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
}

//Intersect
$parameters = array_intersect(array_keys($_GET), $fields);

//Query
$q = array();
foreach($parameters as $parameter) {
    $q[] = $v . '="' . addslashes($_GET[$parameter]) . '"';
}

$q = implode(" AND ", $q);
```

You could probably also try running a DESCRIBE-query on the table instead and parsing those results, but don't know about the performance of DESCRIBE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this to get the fields.

```
$query = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_prof");
$numFields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$vars = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++ )
    $vars[] = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

foreach ($vars as $v)
{
    if (isset($_GET[$v]))
    {
        $query[] = $v.' = "'.addslashes($_GET[$v]).'"';
    }
}
$query = implode(' AND ', $query);
```